# Would destructor be called, if yes, then due to which vector?

Tags: c++, vector, destructor

I have seen many online articles and books but still i'm not able to reach the answer. 
The code is::

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class a
{
public :
    ~a()
    {
        cout << "destroy";
    }
};
int main()
{
   vector <a*> *v1  = new vector<a*>;
   vector <a> *v2  = new vector<a>;
   return 0;
}
```

The answer is "no destructor call" but i not able to understand why??
thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to understand the meaning and purpose of `new`. Or, you can be smart and just *never use `new`*, and you'll never need to learn about this stuff.

Comment: new is used to dynamically allocate the memory in the memory area called heap

Comment: @KerrekSB And then there are Qt developers :)

Comment: Not only you have to create your vectors, you also have to fill them with data so this data can be destroyed. Also, you're creating pointers to vectors, which would require you to delete the vectors themselves in order to destroy their data (in case their contents are also pointers, you would have to delete them first).

Comment: @RichardCritten,i'm not asking any code improvement,I want to just ask how does the  output  of the above ques is "no destructor call" .

Comment: What compiler are you using?. There's no "no destructor call" literal in your code so obviously this is not something you're doing...

Comment: I guess this is someone who learns c++ and want to understand the things and not a "it does not work problem". So suggesting fixes would not be in the interests of the question

Comment: @TheMarlboroMan Sir,by saying output i want to convey that not something that prints on the console but the answer of this question is that      no destructor will be called.

Comment: @sagg1295 I hope my answer helped you a bit. If not feel free to ask

Comment: Ohhh ok. That's right. No destructor is called because of the answers outlined below. Basically: 1- There's no data inside your vectors. If you don't put objects of the type "a" inside the vector there's nothing to destroy. 2 - Your vectors are all created in the "heap" by "new" so in order to empty them, you have to "delete" them. That would destroy the contents. 3 - One of your vectors is a vector of pointers. Were you to put data inside, you would have to manually call "delete" on each of the contents in order for the destructor to execute.

Comment: c++ general rule of thumb: when you create something with new you have to delete it manually somewhere. There are several books and articles which are about avoiding using `new` though and how to use other mechanisms. So try not to get used to it too much :)

Comment: thanks @TheMarlboroMan for ur explaination

Comment: @sagg1295 As Hayt said above: try not to get too familiar with new (at least to create potentially dangling pointers like these). There's a host of std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr that will delete themselves when they go out of scope. As for the rest, there are good explanations in the answers below.

Comment: @BlackMoses: I thought those use a UI toolkit to create XML files that are magically compiled into webapps and mobile IAPs :-) Click'n'drop'n'profit.

Comment: Good ol' Qt makes me cringe everytime I use `new` but still works.

Comment: @KerrekSB Well, `ui` is good and all, but for moar complex widgets, run-time widgets creation and custom widgets it's pretty useless. Example: Custom widget containing 5 standard widgets in its layout. Now I want to be able to add this type of widget in real time to scroll area vertical layout (without limit). `ui` starts to cry at this point.

Answer (score 3):

You're "new"ing your objects so in order to destroy them, you must delete them.

In your first line you're creating a pointer to vector of pointers, so you would have to delete the contents in order for the destructor to execute. Deleting the vector would empty them, but the memory for their contents would be forever lost.

In your second line you're creating a pointer to a vector of objects. When destroying your vector (by deleting it), the destructors would execute.

In any case, you're not filling your vectors with any data so there's no destruction to speak of.

Answer (score 2):

For a destructor to be called the object needs to be deleted.

When you have a local variable on the stack like

```
vector<a> v3;
```

The destructor of v3 will be called, which calls the destructors of the elements when it goes out of scope.

When you use pointers and they go out of scope the destructor to the object they point to is not called.

In your case you have **manually allocated** memory on the heap so you need to **manually deallocate** it.

So when you add

```
delete v2;
```

It will delete the vector v2 and it's elements.

v1 now is a pointer to a vector of pointers. So even

```
delete v1;
```

will not be enough because it just deletes the pointers in the vector not the object. You will have to call delete manually for each element inside the vector before deleting the vector.

Comment: Thanks @Hayt for explaination.

Comment: Pointers don't have destructors. The phrase "their destructors" doesn't make sense.

Comment: The memory doesn't need to be "on the heap". Storage is in general orthogonal to lifetime. E.g. `char buf[sizeof(T)]; new (buf) T;` will also not call destructors, even though no "heap" is involved.

Comment: I have reworded the thing with pointer destructors. The point was more on the "manually" while the memory is on the heap it's more to say if you manually allocate you have to manually deallocate. You can also have pointers to stack objects but usually you should not deallocate them manually.